# Need to click a bid button with Grease monkey script

Tags: xpath, greasemonkey

I'm a bit stuck. I'm trying to create an Grease Monkey script that will automatically click an pop-up that appears on an auction site. I'v got the Xpat, but i'm too in expierienced with GM to get it to work.

Here is theelement inspection line i get from fire finder for firebug:

```
<input type="submit" style="width: 160px;" class="simplemodal-close" id="ctl00_mainContentPlaceholder_Button3" onclick="closePopup(); return false;" value="Back To Auctions" name="ctl00$mainContentPlaceholder$Button3">
```

and the firpath, xpath line is:

```
.//*[@id='ctl00_mainContentPlaceholder_Button3']
```

xpather line for full xpath:

```
/html/body/form[@id='aspnetForm']/div[@id='simplemodal-container']/div/div[@id='basic-modal-content']/div[@id='modal_winningBanner']/div/div[2]/div[2]/input[@id='ctl00_mainContentPlaceholder_Button3']
```

So what i used in my gm script to try to get it to click the button is as follows:

```
// @include *
// @version 0.1
// @description Automatically click // ==/UserScript==

click_popupBtn1 = function() {

var joinBtn=document.evaluate('//*[@id, "ctl00_mainContentPlaceholder_Button3"]'
    ,document,
      null,
     XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE,
     null).singleNodeValue.click();
  alert(joinBtn);
       if(!joinBtn) return false;
          joinBtn.click();
      return true;
}


click_popupBtn1 ();
```

I think ive got something wrong on the syntax, but dont know how to debug GM. I've only worked with turbo pascal a few years ago, but would like to get some simple things done in java and GM.

Any help would be apreciated.

Thanks 
Ludwig

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer with explanation of the reason for the problem and its correction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

umm, I don't understand a lot of the words you used or this complex syntax.

but something like:

```
document.getElementById("ctl00_mainContentPlaceholder_Button3").click();
```

should work.

Comment: @ jonathon  Thanks, didnt think of the getelemntbyid syntax. i used it in the script, and it worked. `clickpopBtn1 = function() {
 var popBtn=document.getElementById("ctl00_mainContentPlaceholder_Button3");
      

  popBtn.click(1);`

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> var joinBtn=document.evaluate('//*[@id, "ctl00_mainContentPlaceholder_Button3"]'
>                               ,document,      
>                                null,     
>                                XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE,
>                               null).singleNodeValue.click();
> ```

**The first argument above is not a syntactically legal XPath expression.**

**Should be**:

```
//*[@id = "ctl00_mainContentPlaceholder_Button3"]
```

Comment: Thanks dimtre, ive tried it, but for some reason i cant get it to click the button with this expression. but with the document.getElementById expression i do get it to work. with time i guess i'll find my mistake, and then kick myself for it :P

Comment: Edited the heading, This works for the bidbuttoms,but still hav a problem ith the popup.