# Need to Click Popup with Gm script that is not always there

Tags: xpath, greasemonkey

i'm still having a problem clicking a popup button on an [auction site](http://www.trada.net/p_home.aspx),that appears only if u won an auction. This popup seems tbe a problem. Ive managed to get help partially in [Need to click a bid button with Grease monkey script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6077020/), i'm able to get the bid buttons clicked, but the popu is stil a problem. The xpath for the popup is:

.//*[@id='ctl00_mainContentPlaceholder_Button3']

And the script i'm using currently is:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           click popup try1.3
// @include         http://www.trada.net/*

// ==/UserScript==


//  ctl00_mainContentPlaceholder_Button3

function PopClick ()
{var PopBtn1=document.getElementById("ctl00_mainContentPlaceholder_Button3");




alert('try1');      
PopBtn1.click (1);
alert('finished');
};

PopClick();
```

But the problem seems to be that the script doesnt stay active on the page waiting for the popup, I think if i can get it to "wait" for the popup to appear, it should work. I'm very new to GM, so excuse if there is simple errors. I had exelent help from people like Brock sofar, who is showing me the ropes. Slowly but surely I'm gettin the hang of it. Remove the alerts, i just used them to see if it executing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to run this function, say every second, thus "waiting" for the popup to appear:

```
setInterval(PopClick, 1000);
```

It is also better to rewrite PopClick to check if the element is there, before calling click, like this:

```
function PopClick () {
    var PopBtn1=document.getElementById("ctl00_mainContentPlaceholder_Button3");
    if(PopBtn1) {
        PopBtn1.click ();
        // It is also makes sense to clear interval here. see docs for setInterval/clearInterval please :)
    }
};
```

May be this will help you with the freezing issue.

The more proper way, however, would be to set up [MutationEvent](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-mutationevents) listener. Since you are using Firefox, it should work OK:

```
function click_if_popup(evt) {
    if(evt.target.hasAttribute('id') && evt.target.getAttrubute('id') =="ctl00_mainContentPlaceholder_Button3")
    evt.target.click();
}

document.addEventListener('DOMNodeInsertedIntoDocument', click_if_popup);
```

Sorry, I didn't test any of this code: I wanted just to give you the general idea of where to dig.

Comment: When i use it like this setInterval(PopClick, 1000);, most of the time the page freezes. If i change it to 10 seconds, it is okay. Thanks.

Comment: @Ludwig, I updated the answer. You may want to try another approach I added.